# No Go with Faucet Puller to Remove Handles

Tags: faucet, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

Trying to replace double sink bathroom faucets from the 1980s and after removing setscrews tried to pull of handles after oiling them and using a Husky faucet puller.  No luck with the Husky and no luck unscrewing the threaded pipe that attaches to the lower silver bell of the handle (it moves up and down the threads but not past the faucet handle). Am I missing something?

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you say set screw, you mean the screw that goes into the top of the handle?  That should be the only thing holding the handle on.  Well, that and 30 years of corrosion...  What tool are you using?

Comment: If this is a particular moen one, that was only briefly produced it's because it's backwards that all other faucets. It took me and two hours of a plumber's time to get it out.

Answer (score 1):

No!  Don’t cut it out!   Unthreading the bell/escutcheon counterclockwise while holding the valve assembly will remove the escutcheon AND the lever.  Several kohler, grohe , price pfister model lavatory faucets install and uninstalled this way.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wishing to replace all of the faucet for a new one or just the handles?
For full replacement,  there should be a locknut on the underside which needs to be removed and also the water line connections.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, cut it out! If you've tried penetrating oil, a puller and maybe whacking up and down on the handle with a hammer (breaks any scale or rust locking) or blow torch (extreme heat expands the outer member) and nothing works.

Then, remove the underside's locking nuts, as seen in picture 2, and just cut them off with a reciprocating saw. If a locking nut doesn't budge, then cut a slot in that to then pry open and off with a screwdriver. Do not let it win!

Answer (score 0):

Vineger. Spray the treads & the underside of the handle with white vinegar, a lot, & let it sit for about 5-10 minutes try twisting it both ways to see if it loosened at all. Repeat if necessary. It will come loose. PLUMBER 20+ YRS